# Sharepoint Filter Blocking Custom View contents

Tags: view, custom-view

I am new to Sharepoint coding. I checked multiple places in order to suppress this strange behavior but could not find anything. The issue is as follows.

If I open the Sharepoint link *(Say sharepoint1.com/sites/Deliverables/one.aspx#)* The custom view (Table format) opens up flawlessly. However if I put a filter on one of the Column Header and share that link, or re open that link in a new tab

*(Say sharepoint1.com/sites/Deliverables/one.aspx#InplviewHash5..)*

The table loads with absolutely no data and none of my JS script work.

Any leads on this? Did I screw up this basic functionality because of my JS file or can I avoid this behavior? - Thanks in Advance

Comment: SharePoint version? (2010,13,16,19, Online)?  Classic or Modern UI?

Comment: Hi, (Online & Modern UI)